# What are the electric and magnetic fields of an arbitrarily moving point charge assuming instantaneous field propagation for simplicity?

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-electrodynamics

I could find an equation for the magnetic field. It is called the Biot-Savart law:
$$
{\vec{\pmb{B}}} = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi} \cdot q \cdot \frac{1}{r^2} \cdot \left( {\vec{\pmb{v}}} \times {\hat{\pmb{r}}} \right)
$$
But I could not find an equation for the electric field. I guess it is the following:
$$
{\vec{\pmb{E}}}=\frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0} \cdot q \cdot \frac{1}{r^2} \cdot {\hat{\pmb{r}}} \;\;- \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi} \cdot q \cdot \frac{1}{r} \cdot {\vec{\pmb{a}}} \;\;- \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi} \cdot q \cdot \frac{1}{r^2} \cdot \left( {\vec{\pmb{v}}} \cdot  {\hat{\pmb{r}}} \right) \cdot  {\vec{\pmb{v}}}
$$
What are the correct equations? And do you have sources for it?

Answer (score 1):

In the limit $c\rightarrow\infty$, electromagnetism becomes electrostatics, and the fields are simply

$$\vec{E}=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{q}{r^2}\hat{r}$$

and

$$\vec{B}=0.$$

The Liénard-Wiechert fields of an arbitrarily moving point charge, written in SI units, can be found in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li%C3%A9nard%E2%80%93Wiechert_potential). Simply take the limit $c\rightarrow\infty$, while assuming that the velocity and acceleration of the point charge are finite, and you will get the above electrostatic fields.

The lesson here is that assuming instantaneous field propagation "for simplicity" loses all of the interesting physics! One of most interesting things about electromagnetism is that it was the first theory about a fundamental field with a *finite* speed of propagation, which led eventually to Special Relativity.

By the way, electromagnetism is nicer in Gaussian units. Take a look at equations (19) and (20) [here](http://users.wfu.edu/natalie/s13phy712/lecturenote/lecture27/lecture27latexslides.pdf) for the Liénard-Wiechert fields of an arbitrarily moving point charge in these units. No silly $\epsilon_0$ and $\mu_0$!

If you are puzzled about how the Biot-Savart law (for a charge in *uniform* motion) gives $\vec{B}=0$ in the limit $c\rightarrow\infty$, use the relationship in SI units between $\epsilon_0$, $\mu_0$, and $c$, namely $c=1/\sqrt{\epsilon_0\mu_0}$. You can write this as $\mu_0=1/\epsilon_0c^2$ so you can see that $\mu_0\rightarrow 0$ as $c\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: While your answer is formally correct for $c \rightarrow \infty$,
it still makes sense to keep the biggest non-zero term of the magnetic field,
thus recovering the Biot-Savart law: 
$\vec{B} = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi} \frac{q\vec{v}}{r^2} \times \hat{r}$.

Comment: If you want the leading terms as $c$ becomes large but not infinite, I agree.